# How to pass an array into IN() clause?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$str = 'In My Cart : 11 12 items';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches); // output is two number: 11, 12
```

Now I want to know, how can I pass this array `$matches` to this query?

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN ($matches); // actually I want something like this: IN (11, 12)
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `implode` -

```
"SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (" .implode(',', $matches[0]) . ")";
```

Comment: Seems correct, Thanks ... (I will check it and accept it as my answer if worked correctly). +1 upvote

Comment: Well, there is a small problem, the output of this `implode(',', $matches)` is this: `array`! I think I need two `implode()`

Comment: Can you add `var_dump($matches)`?

Comment: `array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "11" [1]=> string(2) "12" } }`

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: In your opinion, do I need to use prepared statements in this case? I think it is not necessarily, because the output is just numbers, am I right?

Comment: Using prepared statements is a good practice.